# error: package directory '<project_name>' does not exist

Tags: python, pip

I have a simple Python package I've created. I copied the `setup.py` file from the [Python docs](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html), but when I run `pip install .` I get the following error:

```
~/Projects/wolfgang (master) $ pip install . Processing /Users/Cisplatin/Projects/wolfgang
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/wolfgang.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/wolfgang.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/wolfgang.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/wolfgang.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/wolfgang.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    error: package directory 'wolfgang' does not exist

    ---------------------------------------- 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/k5/grp3jdnn5jvcd14ffvqyr9z00000gn/T/pip-pWAjtJ-build/
```

I've tried searching online and there seem to be some similar problems on GitHub or StackOverflow, but they all apply to something being broken in the project itself as opposed to the `setup.py` file. My program does not mess around with any command line arguments or anything like that, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/Cisplatin/wolfgang/blob/master/setup.py) to the actual `setup.py` file I'm using, if that helps.

Comment: your setup.py link is broken. Can you please fix it?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no setup.py in your repository because [you removed it](https://github.com/Cisplatin/wolfgang/commit/f5c10ab8c1f5cfb65128faec96e09f84a00283b0).
2. There have to be a subdirectory **wolfgang**. Both __init__.py and vector.py must be in the subdirectory.

Comment: How can I make the package directory the current directory (i. e. one directory up from 'wolfgang')?

Comment: @Thomas This layout can only be used to install one independent `.py` module. If you want to install a package (a directory with `__init__.py` with many `.py` modules) you must put it into a subdirectory.